# Sorting integers in Java with extra condition

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a few variables (int) by size with the added condition, that when two are equal they should be sorted alphabetically. More specifically:

I have the following method:

```
public void doSomething(int carrots, int mushrooms, int salads, int tomatoes) {
    //Here I want to print them in the right order
}
```

The printed lines should have the format: "mushrooms: [amount]"
And only lines which are not 0 should be printed.
These things I can manage on my own however.

I have tried to put them all in a List and sort them, but then its basically impossible to map them back to their names.
I don't really know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of an academic approach. The other answer is a better practical approach.

Since the arguments are already alphabetical, and java's sort algorithm is stable. ie if the two values are the same, then they'll stay in the same order, then.

```
List<Integer> amount = new ArrayList<>(List.of(carrots, mushrooms, salads, tomatoes));
List<Integer> sorted new ArrayList<>(amount);
sorted.sort(Integer::compare);
```

Now you can map the items back because the order doesn't change when they're equal.

```
String[] names = {"carrots", "mushrooms", "salads", "tomatoes"};

for(Integer i: sorted){
    if(i == 0) continue; //skip zero values.

    int j = amount.indexOf(i);
    System.out.println( names[j] + " : " + i );
    amount.set(j, -1);
}
```

If the values are all unique, then it is obvious how this works. It finds the index of the value, and prints the corresponding name.

When there are duplicates, the alphabetically lowest name is printed first. The value is replaced with `-1` so that subsequent calls to "indexOf" return the next valid index.

Answer (score 2):

Use a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = Map.of(
        "carrots", carrots,
        "mushrooms", mushrooms,
        "salads", salads,
        "tomatoes", tomatoes
);
counts.entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 0)
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s: [%d]%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

I know that `.<String, Integer>` is ugly, but Java's type inference can't see past the first call in method chains. This tells the compiler that the the first method in the method chain uses `String` and `Integer` as generic types.